# URL to make SSMS start and connect to a db?

Tags: sql, url, cmd, ssms

It would be nice to have a bunch of reference links somewhere, that could also be used to start SSMS.

Is this possible? and get it to use an already open instance?

e.g. sqlwb -E -S Server\instance

but I'm not sure if you can do this in the form of a URL

i.e. how to make a URL run CMD

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your shortcut for SSMS (or copy existing one),i.e. that thing on which you click to open SSMS.

Open Properties --> tab Shortcut.
Add options to target text box

For ex., I have:
"D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" -nosplash -S localhost -d  _A
to avoid splash, to connect automatically to database __A, etc.
[image]

You will get help by adding non-existent option
[image]

, pressing OK, double-click shortcut

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this in a URL directly, but you could certainly create URLs to `.cmd` batch files (in the form of a UNC path) which contained the relevant commands.

Answer (score 0):

To make a "url" run a cmd file, format it in this way:

```
file:///c:\folder path\myfile.cmd
```

If you want to embed one of these file links in a document (like Word or email) then you may need to add angle brackets around it:

```
<file:///c:\folder path\myfile.cmd>
```

and the editor will make it into a link automatically. (alternatively you could just highlight some text, right click and create a file hyperlink using the first syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Launching executables from URL is a very bad idea and a security hole. I advise to avoid doing this for many reasons.